# showing loading images before displaying any control on button click event in vb.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Display ajax loading image before loading anycontrol ......... means if i wanna show textbox on button click after showing loading images using ajax toolkit or ajax extension in vb.net ?

Comment: is this a question or confusion?

Comment: This is question means i wanna show loading images before page loads or any controls load .... in vb.net !

Answer (score 0):

This is an action on the client side so no server code can do this for you, you need Javascript code on the client to do this for you.
take a look at

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/